# why won't my ps3 go online?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

How do you fix getting online for ps3?
When I try to go online it says

> error you have been logged out of psn

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Any answer or comments would be nice -- thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your connection?  According to what you're telling us, you have a connection.  Are you trying to play a specific game or something?  We need more information.

Comment: I'm trying to play call of duty black ops 1. zombies, multiplayer, etc.

Comment: Is there a code that does with your error?  Does this only happen on Black Ops or all games?  Can you access any online service (store, netflix, etc)?

Comment: I can access online stores etc and it happens with all games I'll check the code.

Comment: can't access online stores

Comment: double check your network connections. Make sure you are connected properly and run a test connection. This will tell you if it is able to connect to your home network, obtain an IP address, connect to the internet, and connect to the playstation store. If you cannot then you will have to redo your network connection. This is a very easy procedure and will give you a lot better information to give us here.

Comment: sorry it took so long to comment back been very busy. I ran a connection test every thing was good,but when it god to psn it said failed.

Comment: sorry I mean got

Comment: (80710d23) this is th code

Comment: i can't go online to do anything

Comment: Is this a new occurance or started from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your Network connection by browsing ..
If its stopped working then the problem from your connection .. otherwise, please provide the error number (the one you get when you face the problem).

Comment: 80710d23 is the error code

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have to do some port forwarding. Is this so? Try this...
http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network/port-forwarding/td-p/27398723

Comment: how do you add ports?

Comment: If you are confident to. Also ensure to backup your router settings or be prepared and know where the factory reset is on your router. You have to access your routers administration settings, and there will be a menu option of port forwarding.